# If data is less than set limit, taking too much time

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariasql

I have a table having 200K rows. When I execute a query it's taking too much time; approximately 2 minutes.

This is my query:

```
SELECT a,b,c,d,@row:="tag1" as tag 
  FROM tableName
 WHERE tagName like "%helloworld|%"
 ORDER BY viewCount desc
  LIMIT 20;
```

`helloworld|` occurred only in 2 rows.

I want to change the query so if the data is present more than 20 times, it should return 20 rows else whatever rows present.

How to optimize this query?

Comment: That runs a full table scan. Try fulltext search instead

Comment: You need to create separate table with tags to have ability of filtering without fullscan.

Comment: Try fulltext index on `tagName` column together with `MATCH AGAINST`, i.e.: `WHERE MATCH(tagName) AGAINST('helloworld|' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`

Comment: Read this -- sargable queries are queries that can exploit indexes. Yours cannot. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable

Comment: Unless your rows are very wide or you are on a very slow computer, scanning 200,000 rows should take seconds, not minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot speed this up as written.

The WHERE clause with the LIKE requires that you scan each and every row.  It's O(N), where N = # of rows in the table.  It will run more slowly as your table size increases.

You can make the query run faster if you can find a way to parse that string into tokens that you can INSERT as columns and index.

Answer (score -1):

Try these

1. Set index on your search field of your table & then check the query execution time
2. Not sure what's viewCount here but i guess you are getting this with subquery try to remove order statement & then check the query execution time